# Projections.countDistinct with Hibernate produces unexpected result

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, criteria

I have the following code

```
Criteria criteria = this.getCriteriaForClass(DeviceListItem.class);
Projection rowCountProjection = Projections.countDistinct("color");
criteria.setProjection(rowCountProjection);
int rowCount = ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();
return rowCount;
```

, whose purpose is to find out the number of rows with different values for the field named "color". The problem is that

```
Projections.countDistinct("color");
```

returns the same number of results as

```
Projections.count("color");
```

even though there are multiple rows with same color in the database view. When converting the Criteria object to SQL, I see that the SQL produced by Hibernate is

```
select count(this_.COLOR) as y0_ from DEVICESLIST_VIEW this_ where 1=1
```

when I would expect it to be

```
select count(distinct this_.COLOR) as y0_ from DEVICESLIST_VIEW this_ where 1=1
```

Why doesn't it work like expected and is there some remedy? Unfortunately I have no option to use HQL in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug, fixed in 3.5.2: [HHH-4957](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4957).